# Is this pass by reference or by value?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Lets say I have the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    // ...
}

void doSomething (MyClass instance)
{
    // Is instance passed by reference or by value (copied)?
}

void main ()
{
    MyClass instance = MyClass();

    doSomething(instance);
}
```

In `doSomething()` is `instance` passed by reference? Or is the class duplicated in memory? Or something else?

Comment: What goes on behind the scenes? Is the whole object duplicated in memory?

Comment: You have to look what the copy constructor does.

Comment: you param `instance` gets constructed by copy constructor defined by compiler in this case .

Comment: Hopefully you have a default constructor otherwise MyClass() won't work.

Comment: C++ calls a copy constructor in the above case and passes that on. Its a shallow copy. If you want a deep copy you will need to override that in your class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is passed by value

```
void doSomething (MyClass instance)
```

This is passed by reference

```
void doSomething (MyClass& instance)
```

This is passed by const reference

```
void doSomething (const MyClass& instance)
```

Also `MyClass` doesn't need to by constructed by assignment.
So:

```
MyClass mc=MyClass();
```

is effectively the same as:

```
MyClass mc; //no parens needed for default constructor (no args).
```

EDIT:
This is passed by const reference to a const function, a const function can be called on a const object as it guarantees not to modify the object state.

```
void doSomething (const MyClass& instance) const
```

Const correctness is considered good practice in C++ unlike many less strict languages.

see me:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm

Comment: What significance if any does the `const` keyword have other than it cannot be modified in the `doSomething()` method?

Comment: @Ben It allows temporary objects to be passed as an argument.

Comment: Const should be used when ever a function does not need to modify the state of the object just read it. You should mark your functions as const too (ill add an example in min), these function can then be used when the object is const.

Comment: @Ben That's it exactly. Pass by value though inefficient protects the caller from modification of the object by the function. Using const reference offers nearly the same protection. A bad function writer can cast the constness away however.

Comment: So, just so I have it down, when a class object is const, I can only call its const methods, correct?

Comment: @Ben yes, and const member function can not modify the state of the object.

Comment: Ah thats the key thing, it can't modify the state of its parent object. Thanks. Invaluable.

Comment: It is truely is, if you abide by const correctness it will save you from bugs at a later date.

Comment: Note: `MyClass mc=MyClass();` Is **not** the same as `MyClass mc`; The first one forces zero initialization of POD members for classes (or sub classes) that have a default compiler generated constructor. The second one does not force zero initialization and leaves POD members undefined. Just like `int* x1 = new int();` is different from `int* x2 = new int;`

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks I never knew that, edges cases like this are one of the many reasons I don't rely on default constructors for complex classes.

Answer (score 1):

If not explicitly stated, it's not by reference. It's by value.

The following prototype denotes a parameter passed by reference:

```
void doSomething (MyClass& instance)
{
    // Is instance passed by reference or by value (copied)?
    // In this case, by reference
}
```

Indeed, in your case, a new object is most likely created. I say most likely because, as long as observable behavior is the same, it might as well not be. But, in theory, yes, a new object is created for use inside the function.

The new object is created by calling the copy-constructor on the object you pass as parameter. If you haven't defined a copy-constructor, a default is generated by the compiler which does a shallow copy.

Comment: "I say most likely because, as long as observable behavior is the same, it might as well not be" >> couldn't get it, can you explain please?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis the compiler can optimize the extra object out.

Comment: Is there a way to reverse that. What I mean is, is there any way to code `MyClass` such that, if not explicitly stated, IT IS passed by reference, NOT by value?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is copied.

When you call `doSomething`, the `MyClass` copy constructor is called, to create a new instance.

This instance will remain in scope for the duration of the `doSomething` function. When the function ends, the `MyClass` destructor will be invoked for this instance.

(Note that if you haven't written a copy constructor, one is created for you by default.)

So if you add an explicit copy constructor and destructor:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
         MyClass()
         {
             std::cout << "MyClass constructor" << std::endl;
         }
         MyClass(const MyClass& other)
         {
               std::cout << "MyClass copy constructor" << std::endl;
         }
         MyClass::~MyClass()
         {
               std::cout << "MyClass destructor" << std::endl;
         }
}
void doSomething (MyClass instance)
{
    std::cout << "doSomething method";
}

void main ()
{
    MyClass instance = MyClass();
    std::cout << "invoking doSomething" << std::endl;
    doSomething(instance);
    std::cout << "returned from doSomething" << std::endl;
}
```

This will output the following:

- MyClass constructor
- invoking doSomething
- MyClass copy constructor
- doSomething method
- MyClass destructor
- returned from doSomething
- MyClass destructor

Answer (score 1):

it is duplicated on the stack in order to be passed to the function. This can be very expensive if your class has reached a certain amount of bytes as each instance variable has to be laid out on the stack. A class doesn't behave differently than a regular c struct in this case.

so lets say you have 2 ints in you class ( i assume 32 bit system )

```
class A {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

when you declare it in your main, the stack pointer goes down by 8 bytes. 
if you than call your_function(A), C has to copy the layout class to the stack as well, so that your_function can access it after being called. this means the stack pointer goes down again 8 bytes, value gets written in from the old values and the function gets called.

with 2 instance variables this is not a big deal. But image you have a class which hold structs and lets say 20 ints + a virtual table? than i can be a very expensive operation. If you pass by pointer, the stack pointer has to go down by only 4  bytes, copy the address of the class in it and call the function. way more cheap of course.

You can actually try that on your own. Just change some instance variable within the function and than check after the function has returned if your first class has the new value or the value from before the function call. That should give you the answer.

In any case, if that is what you want, you should implement a copy constructor to handle how to copy your variables.